# Trimming MLV or CDNG Footage

Tags: magic-lantern

I need to edit some mlv footage that consists of a number of lengthy takes. Due to the nature of the subject matter, a lot of the footage is effectively unneeded and given the size of mlv files, I want to trim away as much as possible, leaving only relevant footage to work with. I'm not talking about editing the footage. I'm talking about trimming down the original footage, leaving much less source material to then edit.

**How can I trim this footage down?**

If necessary, I can convert the mlv files to cdng files for trimming, though this is far from ideal.

Comment: > I'm not talking about editing... I'm talking about
> trimming... In your terms, what's the difference between 'trimming' and 'editing'? In almost any NLE, the first step when capturing video for editing is choosing which takes to digitize into clips, and 'binning' them appropriately. The material you don't digitize isn't in the system and doesn't occupy any storage in the NLE. What beyond that do you need to do?

Comment: As far as I know I cannot re-export CDNG from Premiere and I definitely can't re-export MLV. This means that by opening the CDNG file in an NLE and trimming the footage, I lose the original format and am stuck with an NLE project depending on all the original footage, or an edited version of the original footage that is no longer a CDNG. I want to trim away the useless footage from the CDNG to save space whilst preserving the format.

Comment: Yes, but... are you eventually going to bring this material into an editing system? If so, that's the point at which you cull. If not, what are you going to do with it?  The idea of digitizing selects is to have a project in the NLE that uses only footage you want to edit with. What am I missing?

Comment: I have around 500GB of MLV footage, most of it is junk, but probably 100GB is gold. I want to archive this footage as well as edit it. I don't want to store 400GB of junk footage, just to store 100GB of good footage. Neither do I want my NLE project linking to so much junk footage. I just want to trim away the crap and archive and work with the good stuff. When I say crap, I mean it's never going to be used for anything. When I say good stuff, this is the material I would draw on when putting an edit together.

Answer (score 1):

[MLRawViewer](http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=9560.0) has functionality that allows a range of an MLV file to be exported as a CNG. There is no ui for it, but when scrubbed to the desired start-point, `i` will set the in-point and when scrubbed to the desired end-point, 'o' will set the out-point.